# logout error "something went wrong"

Tags: logout

I have add a link of logout in menu using wordpress default menu like this http://example/wp-login.php?action=logout it redirects me to logout confirmation but after clicking on logout in confirmation box "something went wrong error" comes.
can someone please help me out.
Thanks
 [image]

Comment: It's probably throwing a red flag because logout links are supposed to use an nonce, and a nav menu item wouldn't have one.

Comment: A nav menu item can have a nonce, but it involves adding a filter to a create and append a nonce to that specific menu node, normally by targeting it based on the CSS class option.